# Regarding Khomeini's speech against USA in Qom-1964?

Tags: united-states, iran

1. What was the significance of Khomeini's Speech against US Capitalisation in Qom, Iran-1964? Is there an easily accessible English translation of this speech?
2. What measures did the US or the Shah take against Khomeini after that speech?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about conspiracy theories and asking for reference material.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based due to point #2, but point #1 should be legit, shouldn't it?

Comment: Voting to Reopen after Toms Edits. It sees reasonable to me now.

Comment: @LennartRegebro agreed. _(I have to point out that the OP doesn't really deserve points for this post IMAO, since his original post was quite bad, and only another user's edit saved it)_

Comment: @Lohoris: Yeah, but that's how SO works.

Comment: @LennartRegebro sure, it was _yet another rant_ agains SO in general.

Answer (score 3):

The 1964 speech was arguably a turning point in [Khomeini's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruhollah_Khomeini) campaign against the Shah. The speech was against the Shah's giving U.S. servicemen "extraterritorial" privileges, the right to be tried for crimes in Iran in American, rather than Irani courts.

It cut pretty close to home and upset the Shah. The Shah didn't try to kill him, but did arrest and imprison him for six months. The final result was exile, and Khomeini stayed abroad for 14 years.

He returned to Iran in 1979, and "the rest is history."